# Conditional redirection appending / overwriting

Tags: bash, shell, redirect, if-statement

I have a condition, depending on which I want to either append or overwrite some file like this:

```
if [ "${CONDITION}" -eq 1 ]; then
   echo "writing some info"
   echo "${INFO1}" > "${FILE1}"
   echo "${INFO2}" > "{$FILE2}"
   ...
else
   echo "Appending some info"
   echo "${INFO1}" >> "${FILE1}"
   echo "${INFO2}" >> "{$FILE2}"
   ...
fi
```

The thing is that `if` and `else` blocks are relatively big (20 lines each) and are essentially identical except the redirection difference. This makes me feel really bad indeed.

How can I avoid this bad style? I.e. I need to have only one block like this and define the append/overwrite action in some other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the condition to open the files in write mode (to create/truncate them), then unconditionally append to them.

```
if [ "${CONDITION}" -eq 1 ]; then
    : > "${FILE1}"
    : > "${FILE2}"
    echo "writing some info"
else
    echo "appending some info"
fi

# Will create files where necessary
echo "${INFO1}" >> "${FILE1}"
echo "${INFO2}" >> "{$FILE2}"
...
```

Comment: Thanks, great answer to my question.

Comment: A very slight improvement: you can use `: > "$FILE1" > "$FILE2"` to open both/all your files on one line. Since you aren't actually trying to redirect any actual output, it does'n't matter that `bash` will open, then close, each file in succession. (As compared to `echo foo > file1 > file2`, which only writes to `file2`, leaving `file1` empty.)

Comment: Will file descriptors be closed automatically when I use this method of writing to files?

Comment: They are. The `if` statement does't actually leave the files open; it just truncates the files if they already exist, so that `: > file1; echo foo >> file1` has the same effect as `echo foo > file1`. It also creates the files if they don't already exist, but that's just a side effect, not a necessary feature, since `echo >> file1` will also create `file1` if necessary. In any case, an output redirection only opens a file for the duration of the the command it is used with.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just have the if statement delete the log files?
Then you've just one set of echoes.
Or if the permissions on the logfiles are very particular you could truncate them without losing the permissions by copying /dev/null to them.
Then the echos are a single set, outside the if statement.
I doubt you need the echo about appending or writing?

Comment: I guess I'll use this one, as it is simple and straightforward. Somtimes one fails to realise such obvious things... That's what is someone else's opinion / expirience for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can factor out the redirection part by using a subshell like:

```
if [ "${CONDITION}" -eq 1 ]; then
   echo "writing some info"
   (echo "${INFO1}"
   echo "${INFO2}") > "{$FILE2}"
   # ...
else
   echo "Appending some info"
   (echo "${INFO1}" 
   echo "${INFO2}") >> "{$FILE2}"
   # ...
fi
```

and then you might refactor the code in the subshells (between the parens)

```
function do_echos {
      echo "${INFO1}"
      echo "${INFO2}"
      # ...
}

if [ "${CONDITION}" -eq 1 ]; then
   echo "writing some info"
   (do_echos) > "{$FILE2}"
else
   echo "Appending some info"
   (do_echos) >> "{$FILE2}"
fi
```

Everything is only written in one place now and you should be able to scale it from there.

### original answer

If all of the lines are identical except for the redirection line then *please* pull all of the lines outside of the conditional.  [Avoiding duplication of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291107/good-strategy-to-avoid-duplicate-code) is a very good idea because you can introduce bugs by changing one copy of the line and failing to realize you also need to change it somewhere else.

Comment: I'll edit my question to better reflect what I was trying to accomplish. However this isn't answering what I wanted to achieve in the first place. Thanks for your suggestion, though!