# bash, how to select if to append in redirection by variable (use either > or >> according to $append )

Tags: bash, redirect

I need in a script , or a function , to direct output to log file , and depending on a variable , to decide if I to append or override

should be something like that ( which obviously does not work..)

```
if [ "$append" = "true" ] ; then direction=">>" ; else direction=">" ; fi
echo $message "$direction" $targetFile
```

and not the trivial answer of using 2 separated command with "if" statement

Later edit , there is a supposed duplicate question  ,here : [Conditional redirection appending / overwriting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32141281/conditional-redirection-appending-overwriting)   ,  however, i like Ivan answer here better than the answers in the other posts

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional redirection appending / overwriting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32141281/conditional-redirection-appending-overwriting)

Answer (score 3):

Use tee

```
if [ "$append" = "true" ] ; then direction="-a" ; else direction= ; fi
echo $message | tee "$direction" $targetFile
```

From tee's help

```
$ tee --help
Usage: tee [OPTION]... [FILE]...
Copy standard input to each FILE, and also to standard output.

  -a, --append              append to the given FILEs, do not overwrite
...
```

Played with this a bit

```
write_to_file () { tee           $2 $1; }
apend_to_file () { write_to_file $1 -a; }

case "$append" in
    1|[Yy]|[Yy]es|[Tt]|[Tt]rue) direction=apend_to_file;;
    *                         ) direction=write_to_file;;
esac

echo            $direction
echo $message | $direction $targetFile
```

Comment: Note that to get the OP's desired behavior, you should add `> /dev/null` (since otherwise the output will be duplicated to standard output).

Answer (score 3):

Solution1: Open a dedicated file descriptor in the desired mode

```sh
if [ "$append" = "true" ] ; then
  exec 3>>"$targetFile"
else
  exec 3>"$targetFile"
fi
# Output to targetFile using the pre configured mode
echo "$message" >&3
```

Solution2: Always append but conditionally erase overwrite the file content:

```sh
if [ ! "$append" = "true" ] ; then
  # Reset target file
  > "$targetFile" # same effect as overwrite
fi
echo "$message" >> "$targetFile"
```

Short form:

```sh
[ "$append" = "true" ] || > "$targetFile"
echo "$message" >> "$targetFile"
```